# WDK Rollsback upon installation

Tags: c, wdk

Good afternoon,

I try to install Windows WDK 10 on a Windows 8.1 Machine currently running Visual studio 2015, it rolls back after sometime during installation I dont seem to understand why it acts so.

Any ideas on how i can resolve this issue?

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on Server Fault.

Comment: @GhostCat The WDK is for software development. Such questions are **in principle** on-topic. But this one lacks information.